# Django makes two <select> instead of one, trying to use Bootstrap (Form upload)

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, templates

So I'm trying to make a website with django and I'm running into a problem where when i create a select list, two shows up.

Html:

```
<form action="/upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">

  <select class="form-control">
      {% for course in form.courseChoices %}
      <option value="{{course}}">{{course}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
  </select>
    <!--div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-12" id="upload_form" -->
        <label class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
            {{ form.document }} <input type="file" style="display: none; width: 100%;" >
        </label>
    </div> </form>
```

This is what is looks like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btd3B.png)

My form is just a simple ModelForm with a couple fields. 
forms.py
`class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FileUploads
        fields = ('semesterChoices', 'document', 'courseChoices',)`

Here is what my model looks like

```
class FileUploads(models.Model):
semestersList = ['Spring 2017',
                 'Fall 2016',
                 'Spring 2016',
                 'Fall 2015',
                 'Spring 2015',
                 'Fall 2014',
                 'Spring 2014',
                 'Fall 2013']
with open('polls/courses.txt', 'r') as f:
    coursesList = [line.strip() for line in f]

semesters = [(option, option) for option in semestersList]
courses = [(course, course) for course in coursesList]
semesterChoices = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=semesters, default="Spring 2017")
courseChoices = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=courses, default="ACCT Accounting")
document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I just want the bootstrap select, but it seems that whatever value is passed into it doesn't really matter, it takes the second select statement as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to adjust your form class as well as your template.

First of all, if you want your form to have a select input for your `courseChoices` you have to explicitly define that on your form. Your model just contains a `CharField` for that and by default, your form will also only provide a `CharField`.

```
from django import forms

from .models import courses as course_choices


FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    courseChoices = forms.ChoiceField(choices=course_choices)

    class Meta:
        model = FileUploads
        fields = ('semesterChoices', 'document', 'courseChoices',)
```

Note that your form now has three fields with one of them being overridden to use a `ChoiceField` instead of a `CharField` and the other to using the default form field for their corresponding model field! If you want to have another `ChoiceField` for your semester choices you have to do the same with this field.

Then in your template you have to manually render your `<select>` field like this:

```
{# stuff before your form #}

<form action="/upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}            

        {{ form.courseChoices.errors }}
        <select name="{{ form.courseChoices.name }}" id="{{ form.courseChoices.id_for_label }}" class="form-control">
            {% for value, name in form.courseChoices.field.choices %}
                <option value="{{ value }}">{{ name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
         </select>

         {{ form.document.errors }}
         <label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
             <input type="file" style="display: none;" name={{ form.document.name }} id={{ form.document.id_for_label }}>
         </label>
    </div>
</form>

{# stuff after your form #}
```

Also see the documentation about [manually rendering form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

I don't know if the file input will work with bootstrap like this.

You can also always render the complete form by just adding {{ form.as_p }} to your template to see how your form should look like unstyled.

In your model you named your field courseChoices which is a litte bit confusing because you actually only store one course at a time in it which is one of the choices you gave it. Therefore it makes no sense to call it courseChoices. Instead you should call your tuple of choices course_choices and your model field just course.

A little side note: 
In python people usually prefer snake case in favor of camel case. So if you want to adapt your coding style use `course_choices` instead of `courseChoices`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked out for me! I'm a noob at Django and this helped me understand that Django was unpacking the form fields and to make it the way I wanted, I would have to manually render the fields.